# how to implement "has_messages_generator" on rails3 with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I already created App that I would like to add "has_message_generator" into it.
an auth plugin "Devise" is already installed,so that I followed these dierection below.

1. Add this line to my Gemfile and did bundle install
   `gem "has_messages_generators"`
2. Did this command line and it seemed everything's ok!
   `rails g has_messages:install user`

But it shows `"uninitialized constant User::HasMessages"` error when I access to root page.
so I took `"include HasMessages"` off from user.rb(in Model directory) 
and did `"bundle exec rake db:migrate"`
It seemed it created table successfully.

Then I tried to access to root page, it still shows error `"undefined method`inbox' for #"`

Anyone has idea with the installation of this plugin???

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [has_messages](https://github.com/ffmike/has_messages), too:

> … to use this you must include `devise` and `has_messages` in your Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks!! ahhh,but has_messages doesn't work on rails3, does it?

Comment: thanks, it actually loaded after I just installed "has_messages" gem. but it now says this error :(  "undefined method `inbox' for #<User:0x00000014d54bc0>"

Comment: 12:   <%= link_to "inbox(#{current_user.inbox(:opened => false).count})", messages_path(:inbox), :id => "inbox-link" %> |
    This looks pretty clear to me :(